# Prompt for input and generate commands based on input

Tags: vbscript, hta

Is there a way to prompt a user for input (several arguments) and pass the input to a command prompt using HTA/VBScript?  The command may take anywhere between 1-2 minutes to run before the next command is executed.  This command returns "results" which I would like to display at the bottom of a window in a frame. This could be tricky since I don't know if there is a return code to check for.

For example: The quick brown input1 jumped over the lazy input2

The user would have to input in the textbox "fox dog" delimited by either a space or a comma.  If the command executes successfully, it will say "the fox was able to jump over the dog" - if the command fails, it will say "the fox fell short".
Several different commands would have to be executed one after another as long as the previous command completes successfully.

Comment: Share your code and ask specific question. Right now you are just asking someone to write the entire code for you.

Comment: You're 100% correct... after I posted, I realized what I am asking.  I am a complete newb and don't know where to start - I am going to do a little research online and come back with something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this as you're not sure where to start and you're thinking about programming an HTA like it is Basic - prompt user -> print answer - when it is actually more like visual basic where you have a form with input boxes and buttons and code that interacts with that form.

The "form" in an HTA is created using HTML (so you need to know some HTML) and the code that interacts with the HTML objects is either Javascript or VBscript*.

I beleive that HTAs offer a great way experiment with programming without having to install servers or import code libraries etc.  You can just open Notepad** and start writing code.

You can copy the code below that does roughly what you describe in your question and use it as a starting point to experiment more.

```
<html>

<style>

    #output {font-size:2em;}

</style>


<script language="vbscript">

sub updateText_OnClick

    output.innerHTML = "The quick brown " & input1.value & " jumped over the lazy " & input2.value  

end sub

</script>


<body>

Brown: <input type="text" name="input1"/>
Lazy: <input type="text" name="input2"/>
<input type="button" name="updateText" value="update"/>

<br/><br/>

<div id="output">The quick brown ? jumped over the lazy ?</div>


</body>

</html>
```

** You can use something like Notepad++ or another code editing program that will highlight your code and make it easier to spot if you have forgotten to close your quotes "" or misspelled a word.

*VBscript no longer works if you use the meta tag  for IE 11 and above.

More example scripts https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/site/search/?f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=HTA&x=0&y=0
I recommend the HTA helpomatic as it has useful code snippets.

Comment: Gordon, I appreciate it very much and will go over your code and learn from it.

Comment: You're very welcome. I've updated my answer and added a link to more examples from Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon... you are very helpful and I will read through your links.